# Regular Expression, C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need help regarding Regular Expression to find a tag/code called 'WAITPHOTO' in a document text. Depending on the presence of WAITPHOTO tag, I will be wrapping text around an Image(left/right of image).
FYI, All the tags starting with PHOTO will be replaced by Image at run-time.

I have some text that looks like:

```
Steps from the drive lead to a terrace with a stone balustrade and open views.  
Front door and double glazed side window lead to the: 
[PHOTOA]
This is text for PhotoA as WAITPHOTO code is followed.
[WAITPHOTO]
SITTING ROOM: 5.11m x 4.61m. Double glazed patio doors to front     
terrace, with open views across Babbacombe. Double glazed window. Television 
aerial point. One screened radiator. One double radiator. 
[PHOTOB]
This text is NOT for PhotoB as WAITPHOTO code is not followed.

Steps from the drive lead to a terrace with a stone balustrade and open views.  
Front door and double glazed side window lead to the: 
[PHOTOC]
This is text for PhotoC as WAITPHOTO code is followed.
[WAITPHOTO]
```

I need to find out if a particular Image tag viz. [PHOTOA] is followed by WAITPHOTO tag.
Also, need to ensure that a particular WAITPHOTO tag is associated with current PHOTO tag and not with the some other following PHOTO tags.

Can anyone please guide me a regular expression to achieve above.

Thank you!

Comment: Have I understood it correctly if want to check that there are no other PHOTOX tags after another PHOTOX tag without first encountering a WAITPHOTO. That is, a PHOTOX tag must be closed with a WAITPHOTO before any others can occur (a PHOTOX tag cannot contain another PHOTOX-WAITPHOTO pair), or the text is not valid?

Comment: hmm, you have understood it well partially :) I want a way to find out if a PHOTOX tag is followed by a WAITPHOTO tag or not.
PHOTOX tag can always be followed by another "PHOTOX-WAITPHOTO"/"PHOTOX".

Comment: Can the tags appear inside other text? For example:
Text is nice, text is cool[PHOTOA]text for photo a[WAITPHOTO]

Comment: Yes, it can be any text that the end user wants while creating word templates and will use PHOTOX tags where he wants to show Images and WAITPHOTO where he wants to wrap text around that image. So, Text will always vary.

Comment: are there and limits on the text that comes in thte [PHOTOX] tag? Could it be [PHOTOBANANAFISHCUP]?

Comment: Yes, these are predefined codes, I know these names at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression worked for me: `(\[PHOTO\w+\])([^\[]+)\[WAITPHOTO\]`

It groups the photo's name tag and the text applied to it.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
string test = @"Steps from the drive lead to a terrace with a stone balustrade and open views.  Front door and double glazed side window lead to the: [PHOTOA]This is text for PhotoA as WAITPHOTO code is followed.[WAITPHOTO]SITTING ROOM: 5.11m x 4.61m. Double glazed patio doors to front     terrace, with open views across Babbacombe. Double glazed window. Television aerial point. One screened radiator. One double radiator. [PHOTOB]This text is NOT for PhotoB as WAITPHOTO code is not followed.Steps from the drive lead to a terrace with a stone balustrade and open views.  Front door and double glazed side window lead to the: [PHOTOC]This is text for PhotoC as WAITPHOTO code is followed.[WAITPHOTO]";
string regex = @"(\[PHOTO\w+\])([^\[]+)\[WAITPHOTO\]";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection mc = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(test, regex);
foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in mc)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    System.Console.WriteLine("This is the photo name: " + m.Groups[1].Value);
    System.Console.WriteLine("This is the photo text: " + m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this regex is that if you have a [ in the photo text then it will not match.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
(\[PHOTO.\]).*?(?<!\1.*?\[PHOTO.\].*)\[WAITPHOTO\]
```

Because I believe that regular expressions are often "write only":

I try to match a [PHOTOX] tag, followed by as little text as necessary (.*?) and a [WAITPHOTO] at the end. To fulfill your need I added a negative lookbehind before the ending WAITPHOTO that says "if there's a [PHOTOX] *between* the starting tag and the WAITPHOTO, fail.